# What is wrong in this higher order function?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

```
mathOp =  function(type){
            return (
               "add" == type?  function(a,b){return a + b}
              :"mul" == type?  function(a,b){return a * b}
              :"sub" == type?  function(a,b){return a - b}
              :"div" == type?  function(a,b){return a / b}

            )
         }
```

Chrome JS debugger tool says: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token )**

What is wrong with this syntax ?

Comment: Please, for the sanity of all the people that maintain your code, change that to a `switch` or `if/ else` statement.

Comment: Ya I got that ! I actually saw this style time back for JS validations.
and I thought its short and sweet but just got to know, what it does to readability of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the last `: else` part.

```
mathOp =  function(type){
            return (
               "add" == type?  function(a,b){return a + b}
              :"mul" == type?  function(a,b){return a * b}
              :"sub" == type?  function(a,b){return a - b}
              :"div" == type?  function(a,b){return a / b}
              : function() { return NaN; /* or throw an exception */ }
            )
         }
```

You could make it more readable by using `switch()`:

```
function mathOp(type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'add': return function(a,b) { return a + b; };
        case 'mul': return function(a,b) { return a * b; };
        case 'sub': return function(a,b) { return a - b; };
        case 'div': return function(a,b) { return a / b; };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As was already mentioned, a : was missing.

However, here's another way to improve this code.  Put the operations in a table (implemented as an object):

```
var ops = {
  add: function(a, b) {return a + b;},
  mul: function(a, b) {return a * b;},
  sub: function(a, b) {return a - b;},
  div: function(a, b) {return a / b;}
};
```

then have `mathOp` perform a table lookup, taking appropriate error-handling if no op is found:

```
function mathOp(mytype) {
    var op = ops[mytype];
    if(!op) {
        ... error-handling ...
    }
    return op;
}
```

This has the advantages that the op functions are only created once instead of each time `mathOp` is called, it's more easily extensible, and the table can be used by other functions if need be.